# Spark-Scala Sending a metadata map of primitive type from driver to executors

Tags: scala, apache-spark, serialization, deserialization

I have a metadata map `M1` of type `Map[String, Map[String, Set[String]]]` which is constructed by querying the database initially when the spark driver is started. We run certain group by on values and then the map is eventaully build by also calling `map(identity)` so that it can be serialized.

This map is being passed along and used to filter/evaluate certain criteria on the actual data read from data lake on multiple exectors.

I would like to understand what would be the ideal way to pass M1 to executors where the actual data resides.

I tried following and it works:

```
 1. val m1:Map[String, Map[String, Set[String]]] = buildMap(DBObject)
 2. @transient val m1:Map[String, Map[String, Set[String]]] = buildMap(DBObject)
```

Other ways I could think of are broadcasting the map as it is quite small comparatively(under 50MB)

Also wanted to understand when I defined the map as transient, I still do not see the map being re-generated on every executor. Why is it happening?